# Are there any good Counting Bloom Filter implementations in Java?

Tags: java, bloom-filter

I'm looking for Counting Bloom Filter implementations in Java. I found the [Hadoop implementation](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/util/bloom/CountingBloomFilter.html) but as far as I can tell it lacks functionality to increase and decrease the count of a member. If it implements the Java Set interface as well this would be a nice feauture but not a must have.

Answer (score 2):

Found this [Apache Hadoop CountingBloomFilter](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/util/bloom/CountingBloomFilter.html).

I tends to trust Apache's libraries.

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged.  If the link changes or gets removed, it invalidates the answer.  Better to post the essentials of the linked info

Answer (score 0):

[java Bloom filters from google projects](http://code.google.com/p/java-bloomfilter/)

Comment: This is an implementation of a classic Bloom filter. I need functionality to remove elements. For example as described here (http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~michaelm/postscripts/esa2006b.pdf), although it describes a specific implementation it is imo easier to understand than the original paper.